# Error on firstrun...?

Tags: boot, 14.04, compiz

So Just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a new system.
4 gigs of memory (but details is reporting 3.8 for some reason?)
AMD FX 8320 CPU
AMD video addin card hd6770
and 2.0 TB HD

I just finished installing from usb and the first boot after logging in, I got an error when I opened the... search / apps menu.
It said compiz crashed, I sent an error report... how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From command line, run:
*sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install*

First time-error, right off the bat, probably an installation issue.